# Win 10 DISM error 0x800f081f /Source options

Tags: windows-10, restore

I noticed this problem when I encountered 2502 and 2503 erros while attempting to install an SDK. I believe I've been having the 250[2|3] errors since upgrading from windows 8.1 to windows 10.

I ran `dism /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth` that responded `The component store is repairable.` so I ran `dism /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` which resulted in the `Error: 0x800f081f`.

**Clarification 11/15/2015 6:45 MST**

*Can someone confirm that this syntax, if successful, is restoring the broken file in question from an online store in the cloud?*

Not the `/Online` option it means that windows is running from the drive being tested.

Note this post by Microsoft employee joscon where he says;

BOGUS! I can't post more than 2 links! http : // blogs . technet . com /b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx

> /RestoreHealth: This checks for component store corruption, records
>   the corruption to C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log and FIXES the corruption
>   using Windows Update.  This operation takes ~10-15mins or more
>   depending on the level of corruption.

Does he meant that Windows Update here means the service in the ms cloud? Or a cache in windows.

At any rate the title of my question should now be regarding "CSI Payload Corupt"

**End clarification 11/15/2015 6:45 MST**

**Additional information 11/15/2015 5:45pm MST**
In another support thread I noticed advice to run `chkdsk /r /f` after runing chkdsk I ran another `sfc /scannow`

From cbs.log;

```
0000561e [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:64{32},l:62{31}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\drivers"\[l:24{12}]"gmreadme.txt"; source file in store is also corrupted
```

From dism.log;

```
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         wow64_multimedia-generalmididata_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_9b1267cc25712003\gmreadme.txt
```

I looked at the file. It's 1kb apparently containing only 'null's Can I just delete it? Also found it on my other machine. Replaced it on bad machine after taking permissions. Still has source file corruption.

How can I tell what dependencies there are on this ?payload? file. If there are none can I delete it? Or preferably uninstall it?

Longer cbs.log snippet taken after the `chkdsk /r /f` note many `Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory` and `is not owned` messages.

```
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    00004688 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:142{71},l:140{70}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Hyper-V\2.0.0.0" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Misc, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    00004689@2015/11/15:20:47:27.647 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    0000468a@2015/11/15:20:47:27.650 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    0000468b Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\wow64_multimedia-generalmididata_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_9b1267cc25712003\gmreadme.txt do not match actual file [l:24{12}]"gmreadme.txt" :
  Found: {l:32 b:TOu/P+8/JAcp+tWxG7JDl9tWiYdagd/TUHpCOPeWZO0=} Expected: {l:32 b:EL9uFcCMjH9dlrZYureK7YbR3iDwjnhx7vugk5rxGgI=}
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    0000468c [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"gmreadme.txt" of Multimedia-GeneralMidiData, Version = 10.0.10240.16384, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    0000468d [SR] This component was referenced by [l:312{156}]"Microsoft-Windows-SKU-Foundation-Package-avcore-noindeo-Group-WOW64-avcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10240.16384.ba5b975ab9b4f73b13c1fb12d02ef8f3"
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    0000468e Hashes for file member \??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\drivers\gmreadme.txt do not match actual file [l:24{12}]"gmreadme.txt" :
  Found: {l:32 b:TOu/P+8/JAcp+tWxG7JDl9tWiYdagd/TUHpCOPeWZO0=} Expected: {l:32 b:EL9uFcCMjH9dlrZYureK7YbR3iDwjnhx7vugk5rxGgI=}
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    0000468f Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\wow64_multimedia-generalmididata_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_9b1267cc25712003\gmreadme.txt do not match actual file [l:24{12}]"gmreadme.txt" :
  Found: {l:32 b:TOu/P+8/JAcp+tWxG7JDl9tWiYdagd/TUHpCOPeWZO0=} Expected: {l:32 b:EL9uFcCMjH9dlrZYureK7YbR3iDwjnhx7vugk5rxGgI=}
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    00004690 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:64{32},l:62{31}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\drivers"\[l:24{12}]"gmreadme.txt"; source file in store is also corrupted
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    00004691@2015/11/15:20:47:27.703 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    00004692@2015/11/15:20:47:27.715 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    00004693@2015/11/15:20:47:27.727 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    00004694@2015/11/15:20:47:27.742 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    00004695 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:164{82},l:162{81}]"\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.0.0.0\en" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft.PackageManagement.resources, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    00004696 Warning - Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory [l:162{81}]"\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.0.0.0\en" in component Microsoft.PackageManagement.resources, Version = 10.0.10240.16384, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    00004697@2015/11/15:20:47:27.758 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    00004698 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:246{123},l:244{122}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\DSCResources\MSFT_PackageResource\en-US" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft.PowerShell.DSCResources.Resources, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2015-11-15 13:47:27, Info                  CSI    00004699 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:246{123},l:244{122}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\DSCResources\MSFT_ProcessResource\en-US" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft.PowerShell.DSCResources.Resources, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}
```

**End Additional information 11/15/2015 5:45pm MST**

**Additional information 11/14/2015 10:20pm MST**

Looking around more forums I found suggestions to run `chkdsk /r/f` after boot I then ran `sfc /scannow` I tried to make a pastebin of the cbs.log, guess it was to large. Here's a snippet showing the gmreadme.txt file as well as just a few of the many errors chkdsk found regarding duplicate ownership and no ownership. I also reran `dism /OnLine /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth` which resulted in the same `0x800f081f` error.

```
2015-11-14 21:38:16, Info                  CSI    00004706@2015/11/15:04:38:16.846 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-14 21:38:16, Info                  CSI    00004707@2015/11/15:04:38:16.858 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-14 21:38:16, Info                  CSI    00004708@2015/11/15:04:38:16.870 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-14 21:38:16, Info                  CSI    00004709 [SR] Verify complete
2015-11-14 21:38:16, Info                  CSI    0000470a [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2015-11-14 21:38:16, Info                  CSI    0000470b [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2015-11-14 21:38:21, Info                  CSI    0000470c Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\wow64_multimedia-generalmididata_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_9b1267cc25712003\gmreadme.txt do not match actual file [l:24{12}]"gmreadme.txt" :
  Found: {l:32 b:TOu/P+8/JAcp+tWxG7JDl9tWiYdagd/TUHpCOPeWZO0=} Expected: {l:32 b:EL9uFcCMjH9dlrZYureK7YbR3iDwjnhx7vugk5rxGgI=}
2015-11-14 21:38:21, Info                  CSI    0000470d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"gmreadme.txt" of Multimedia-GeneralMidiData, Version = 10.0.10240.16384, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch
2015-11-14 21:38:23, Info                  CSI    0000470e [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:174{87},l:172{86}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.ODataUtils" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft.PowerShell.ODataUtils, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2015-11-14 21:38:23, Info                  CSI    0000470f [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:110{55},l:108{54}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft.PowerShell.ODataUtils, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2015-11-14 21:38:23, Info                  CSI    00004710 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:94{47},l:92{46}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft.PowerShell.ODataUtils, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2015-11-14 21:38:23, Info                  CSI    00004711@2015/11/15:04:38:23.366 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-14 21:38:23, Info                  CSI    00004712@2015/11/15:04:38:23.412 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-14 21:38:23, Info                  CSI    00004713@2015/11/15:04:38:23.423 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-14 21:38:23, Info                  CSI    00004714 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:178{89},l:176{88}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\en-US" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft.PowerShell.DSC.Resources, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2015-11-14 21:38:23, Info                  CSI    00004715 Warning - Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory [l:176{88}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\en-US" in component Microsoft.PowerShell.DSC.Resources, Version = 10.0.10240.16384, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2015-11-14 21:38:23, Info                  CSI    00004716@2015/11/15:04:38:23.542 Primitive installers committed for repair
2015-11-14 21:38:23, Info                  CSI    00004717 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:132{66},l:130{65}]"\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.3.5" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft.PowerShell.Pester, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2015-11-14 21:38:23, Info                  CSI    00004718 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:174{87},l:172{86}]"\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.3.5\Functions\Assertions" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft.PowerShell.Pester, pA Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}
```

**End additional information 11/14/2015 10:20pm MST**

**Additional Information 11/13/2015 7:15am MST**

I have another computer with the same configuration. Both machines report Image Version: 10.0.10240.16384 when I run dism. Perhaps the file is available on the *good* machine if so how can I get the file from the *good* machine to the *broken* machine?

*Seems like I've applied several windows updates while this problem has been ongoing. Wonder why they don't fail?*

*Perhaps a readme text file isn't that important. Maybe I should just delete it? If so how?*

I created a .iso with the media creation tool. Then I ran `dism /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth /Source:esd:e:\sources\install.esd:1 /limitaccess` I got the same results. This time I was able to understand the logs a little bit more to notice that the offending file appears to be `gmreadme.txt`

```
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         wow64_multimedia-generalmididata_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_9b1267cc25712003\gmreadme.txt
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
```

It's looking like this file is not available online or on the .iso install.esd to fix this error. Any suggestions on what to try next?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/ckG7VRkr) is a pastebin of dism.log and
[here](http://pastebin.com/rhM9JX81) is a pastebin of cbs.log

**End additional information of 11/13/2015 7:15am MST**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10240.16384

Image Version: 10.0.10240.16384

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The component store is repairable.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10240.16384

Image Version: 10.0.10240.16384

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source l
ocation, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

*I'm not sure how to tell which file it was trying to restore?*

I do have another machine on my LAN that has the same immage and reports `No component store corruption detected` Can I get the file off of this machine? Or mount it as a /Source to Dsim?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10240.16384

Image Version: 10.0.10240.16384

[==========================100.0%==========================]
No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

**Additional Information 11/12/2015 A**

These six lines in the dsim.log were marked error. I'm not clear on how to interpret them.

```
2015-11-12 02:55:56, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=175148 TID=175124 Getting Provider DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::GetProvider
2015-11-12 02:55:56, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=175148 TID=175124 Provider has previously been initialized.  Returning the existing instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider
2015-11-12 02:55:56, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175124 Processing the top level command token(cleanup-image). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine
2015-11-12 02:55:56, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175124 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2015-11-12 02:55:56, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175124 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2015-11-12 02:55:56, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175124 CBS session options=0x48100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175128  Error in operation: source for package or file not found, ResolveSource() unsuccessful. (CBS HRESULT=0x800f081f) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175124 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f081f)
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175124 The source files could not be found; their location must be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175124 Failed processing package changes with session option CbsSessionOptionRepairStoreCorruption - CDISMPackageManager::RestoreHealth(hr:0x800f081f)
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175124 The source files could not be found; their location must be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175124 Failed to restore the image health. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_CleanupImage(hr:0x800f081f)
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175124 Failed while processing command cleanup-image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f081f)
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175124 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=175148 TID=175124 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=175148 TID=175124 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=175148 TID=175124 Found the PE Provider.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=175148 TID=175124 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Package Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 03:07:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=175148 TID=175124 Finalizing CBS core. - CDISMPackageManager::Finalize
```

**Additional Information 11/12/2015 B**

```
Checking System Update Readiness.

(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         wow64_multimedia-generalmididata_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_9b1267cc25712003\gmreadme.txt

Summary:
Operation: Detect only 
Operation result: 0x0
Last Successful Step: CSI store detection completes.
Total Detected Corruption:  1
    CBS Manifest Corruption:    0
    CBS Metadata Corruption:    0
    CSI Manifest Corruption:    0
    CSI Metadata Corruption:    0
    CSI Payload Corruption: 1
Total Repaired Corruption:  0
    CBS Manifest Repaired:  0
    CSI Manifest Repaired:  0
    CSI Payload Repaired:   0
    CSI Store Metadata refreshed:   True

Total Operation Time: 702 seconds.
 - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=141616 TID=41384  - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=141616 TID=41384 <----- Ending corruption detect/repair info -----> - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=141616 TID=41384  - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=141616 TID=41384 DISM has detected a DISM component change. Requesting a shutdown. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Image Session: PID=141616 TID=41384 The image session needs to be closed and re-opened before any servicing operations can be performed. - CDISMImageSession::put_ImageState
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=141616 TID=41384 Loaded servicing stack for online use only. - CDISMPackageManager::RefreshInstanceAndLock
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Found the PE Provider.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Package Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing CBS core. - CDISMPackageManager::Finalize
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(MsiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: MsiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(IntlManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: IntlManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(IBSManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: IBSManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(DriverManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: DriverManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Unattend Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Unattend Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(SmiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: SmiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(AppxManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: AppxManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(ProvManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: ProvManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(AssocManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: AssocManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(GenericManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: GenericManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(OfflineSetupManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: OfflineSetupManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Finalizing the servicing provider(Edition Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: Edition Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Releasing the local reference to OSServices. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Disconnecting Provider: OSServices - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=141616 TID=41384 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=165808 TID=184312 Closing session event handle 0x1a0 - CDISMManager::CloseImageSession
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2015-11-12 02:54:14, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31623/discussion-between-jeff-albrecht-and-ramhound).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31625/discussion-on-question-by-jeff-albrecht-win-10-dism-error-0x800f081f-source-opt).

Comment: ugh, I'll leave both links up for now then - I just wanted to have an archive of the comments up too.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this [post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821) that contained the syntax to mount a good windows 10 of the same build I had on my LAN.

I temporarily shared the c:\ drive from the good machine and mounted it as y: on the bad machine.

I ran the dism, then the sfc. This worked! Unfortunately it didn't fix all my problems with 2502 and 2503 errors with msi installers. As this question is about Source options for dism, and I've answered it I'll take the 2502/3 questions to a new question.

- However, **for the learning**, I'd like to know how to have solved this if I hadn't had a good windows 10 install of the same build available to use as a source to dism.
- While working this problem I noticed many `Duplicate ownership` and `is not owned` messages in cbs.log. I checked a windows 8.1 machine that had about 90% of that many errors. I'm guessing it's not to worry but **wonder what other folks experience is** in their installs.

(ran a bash shell as I'm more comfortable with grep than findstr.)

```
bash-3.1$ grep 2015-11-16 cbs.log | grep  "Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory" | wc
    927   27111  299889
bash-3.1$ grep 2015-11-16 cbs.log | grep  "is not owned but specifies SDDL in component" | wc
    910   26119  297824
bash-3.1$
```

Here are the successful results for the dism and sfc.

```
C:\Windows\System32>Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:y:\windows /LimitAccess

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10240.16384

Image Version: 10.0.10240.16384

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Windows\System32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. We're a Q&A community, not a conventional forum, so answer posts must answer (or attempt to answer) the question—answer posts which fail to do so are subject to deletion. If you'd like to ask a *new* question, click on the **[Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask)** button at the top of the page and enter your question. You may want to include a link to the original question for context.

Comment: The question is: `Win 10 DISM error 0x800f081f /Source options` I answered it with: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:y:\windows /LimitAccess`